# PHP DateTimeZone Member Access

Tags: php

I have a DateTimeZone object, let us call this $TimeZone.

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
    [timezone_type] => 2
    [timezone] => Z
)
```

I want to get timezone_type and timezone as string values.
I have got timezone using the following line-

```
$timezone=$TimeZone->getName();
```

But I am not getting $timezone_type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a thread related to this issue see this:[Here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60873)

A hack can be, you can convert the `object to array` then access the index:

```
$date = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$x=(array) $date;
echo $x['timezone_type'];//3
```